# Basic git/github workflow for project which I will be working on alone at the beginning

Tags: git, github, workflow

I have never worked with version control systems before. I am planning to use git and github for a new project I will be working on. I have gone through git tutorials on Pluralsight. I understand how the system works but as I am new, I find it a bit confusing and want to verify whether I have understood it correctly.

I want to use git for a new project I will be working on. Initially I will be working on the project alone. I guess this would be my workflow.

1. Create a new local repo (git init)
2. Add remote repo (git remote add https://github.com/myuserid/projectname.git)
3. Write/Edit code on local machine
4. Commit changes made in step 3
5. Push commit to remote repo (git push)
6. Go back to step 3 unless you have reached a stage where you want to release a version
7. Add a version tag (git tag -a v1.0)
8. Push tag to remote (git push --tags)
9. Go to step 3

Is this correct?

Edit: One of my friend suggested that I should never commit changes to master on the local repo. I should always create a branch, make changes and commits to it and when I am satisfied, pull them into the local master. Then push them on github. How would you recommend this?

Comment: This is all correct. You can also retroactively tag commits if you forgot to tag one earlier, with the same command with the SHA of the commit you want appended at the end. Also not sure what platform you're on, but there are also some decent git GUI clients that could help you visualize some of this stuff. I recommend [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) on mac.

Comment: @Dima Thanks... I will be primarily using Ubuntu 12.04 and sometimes Windows XP/7.

Comment: Absolutely always do your work on a branch, and after you are done you can delete the branch when you don't need it anymore. That's half the advantage of version control, being able to completely isolate the work you are doing from the working copy.

Comment: Does remote repo already exist?

Answer (score 0):

If remote repo is already exist at https://github.com/myuserid/projectname.git, you better use `git clone` instead of `git init`.

If you use `git clone`,

- Don't need to init the repo. It initializes the repo with the copy of remote repo.
- Don't need to add remote. By default, it creates a remote called `origin`.
- It fetches all branches from remote repo and creates a remote tracking branches for each remote branches in your local repo. This is important, otherwise `git pull` and `git push` don't work properly.

So, I would recommend this workflow:

1. Clone a remote repo (`git clone https://github.com/myuserid/projectname.git`),
2. Write/Edit code on local machine.
3. Commit changes made in step 3 (`git add` and `git commit`).
4. Push commit to remote repo (`git push`)
5. Go back to step 3 unless you have reached a stage where you want to release a version.
6. Add a version tag (`git tag -a v1.0`)
7. Push tag to remote (`git push --tags`)
8. Go to step 3

Comment: Alright. And what are your thoughts on working on a local branch instead of directly on master?

Comment: It's completely alright to work on master branch. The branch 'master' is just another branch, nothing special about it. `Branching` is one of the main feature of git, it lets you work on diff parts of the project simultaneously.